# Qualifiers for printf on WinCE

Tags: printf, windows-ce, qualifiers

On **WinCE**, when using **printf**, what are the qualifiers for various data types - short, unsigned long etc.

For short and ulong, I know the answers are %hd & %lu, I am actually looking for a MSDN site that lists all data types and their qualifiers on CE. Unfortunately I cannot find the site now. I have already looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-printf-an-unsigned-long-long-int), but it does not contain the link or answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this MSDN article : [Format Specification Fields: printf and wprintf Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859632.aspx) (for Platform Builder for Microsoft Windows CE 5.0) answer your question ?

Completed with [**printf Type Field Characters**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859597.aspx), that is.