# format specifier for POSIX data types

Tags: c, gcc, posix

I would like to know what is format specifier for POSIX data types.
    I want to print it using printf().

```
   uint32_t some_long = 10;
   uint16_t some_short = 20;
```

for following data types, please tell me the format specifier

```
int8_t,uint8_t,int16_t  
uint16_t,int32_t,uint32_t   
sa_family_t,socklen_t
in_addr_t,in_port_t 
u_char,u_short  
u_int,u_long
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sprintf for unsigned _int64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140871/sprintf-for-unsigned-int64)

Answer (score 3):

Use stuff like:

```
printf("%"PRIu32, some_long);
```

Similarly you can use `PRIu8`, `PRId16`, `PRIu64` etc. Also, these aren't POSIX-specific, they're standard.

You need to make your own printing routines for the other types you mentioned (like `sa_family_t`).

Comment: Never seen these before (not claiming they don't exist btw), and can't seem to locate them in the C99 standard.