# sprintf uint64_t in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, printf

In Linux I need to `sprintf` `uint64_t`
This is how it defined in "stdint.h"

```
typedef unsigned long int   uint64_t;
```

What should i pass to `sprintf`?

Comment: Does [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140871/sprintf-for-unsigned-int64) apply at all?

Comment: [This reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might be useful.

Comment: `uint64_t` defined in stdint.h

Comment: Next time, search before posting.  My colleague has the same question, but I found the answer by searching.

Answer (score 2):

The header `<inttypes.h>` defines macros to be used with the `*printf` and `*scanf` functions for the types defined in `<stdint.h>`.

To format a `uint64_t` value in decimal:

```
uint64_t n = ...;
sprintf(str, "%" PRIu64, n);
```

The `PRIu64` macro expands to a string literal, which is concatenated with the `"%"` to form a valid format string.