# Strange "unsigned long long int" behaviour

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you printf an unsigned long long int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-printf-an-unsigned-long-long-int)

```
#include <cstdio>

int main ()
{
    unsigned long long int n;
    scanf("%llu",&n);
    printf("n: %llu\n",n);
    n /= 3;
    printf("n/3: %llu\n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Whatever I put in input, I get very strange output, for example:

```
n: 1
n/3: 2863311531
```

or

```
n: 2
n/3: 2863311531
```

or

```
n: 1000
n/3: 2863311864
```

What's the reason? How should I do this correctly?

(g++ 3.4.2, Win XP)

Comment: Can you please write, what is the value of sizeof(unsigned long long int) ? And try 'unsigned long int' instead of '..long long..'

Comment: Also works for me on GCC 4.2.1

Comment: sizeof(unsigned long long int) returns 8. I've changed variable type to unsigned long int and it worked fine, but sizeof(unsigned long int) returns 4, so it's regular int. I need wider range.

Comment: `#include <cstdio>` implies C++, but `unsigned long long int` and `%llu` imply C. Which do you want to use?

Comment: And I've checked the same code on Linux and it works fine...

Comment: Thank you Charles! I've replaced <cstdio> with <stdio.h> and everything's ok :)

Comment: `#include <cstdio>` with `using namespace std;` also works. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Strange, the error sounds like you were calling a `printf` without a prototype in scope. While this would explain the behaviour if you were compiling as C (it would be undefined behavior), the fact that `using namespace std` "worked" suggests that you were compiling as C++ which means that calling `printf` without a prototype should have caused a compile error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that MinGW relies on the `msvcrt.dll` runtime. Even though the GCC compiler supports C99-isms like `long long` the runtime which is processing the format string doesn't understand the `"%llu"` format specifier.

You'll need to use Microsoft's format specifier for 64-bit ints.  I think that `"%I64u"` will do the trick.

If you `#include <inttypes.h>` you can use the macros it provides to be a little more portable:

```
int main ()
{
    unsigned long long int n;
    scanf("%"SCNu64, &n);
    printf("n: %"PRIu64"\n",n);
    n /= 3;
    printf("n/3: %"PRIu64"\n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that MSVC doesn't have `inttypes.h` until VS 2010, so if you want to be portable to those compilers you'll need to dig up your own copy of `inttypes.h` or take the one from VS 2010 (which I think will work with earlier MSVC compilers, but I'm not entirely sure). Then again, to be portable to those compilers, you'd need to do something similar for the `unsigned long long` declaration, which would entail digging up `stdint.h` and using `uint64_t` instead of `unsigned long long`.

Comment: The `SCNu64` and `PRIu64` macros are not valid for use with `unsigned long long`. If you want to use them, you need to declare `n` as `uint64_t`.