# How to get answers of calculations in form of exponent(i.e-6.6.7e-11) in C language

Tags: c

I am new to stackoverflow so sorry for my inappropriately long question or format of question.

I tried this program to calculate gravitational force.so far i have tried these things and they don't seem to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define G 6.67e-11


main()

{

 long double r;

 long double m1,m2,F;
printf("Enter m1:-");
scanf("%Lf",&m1);
printf("Enter m2:-");
scanf("%Lf",&m2);
printf("Enter distance between m1 and m2:-");
scanf("%Lf",&r);
F=(G*m1*m2)/(r*r);
printf("The force is:-%Le",F);

return; 

}
```

Now i have tried many variations in the last line of code.

```
printf("The force is:-%e",F);
```

like instead of %e i have tried %Lf as i have defined F as long double.
also when i run the code as is above and enter the following inputs

ie.

```
Enter m1:10

Enter m2:2

Enter m3:10
```

answer as

```
 force is:1.327e-317
```

instead of 1.334e-11.

which i calculated in calculator.

and if there is a problem with #define please elaborate about how i can define constants in exponential form and use them for similar calculations.

please help.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` takes the address of the variable to be able to write into it but `printf` takes the value as a parameter.
Since `printf` is a variable arguments function, it is unable to check parameters type so you have to pass the proper types.

do that instead:

```
printf("The force is:-%e",F);
```

I have followed the link and adding that switch works for me on windows:

```
-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO

The force is:-1.334000e-011
```

Comment: yes thank you i removed the ampersand sign. and ran the code with double as data type. and %e in last printf but the output in force is #QNAN0e+000

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong format specifier to print the result.

`F` is of type `long double`, but `%e` is used for `double`.  You need to use `%Le`.

Using the wrong format specifier results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, you need to pass in `F`, not `&F` for `printf`.

Comment: Sir i just tried as you suggested but unfortunately the ans still comes out to be 1.327e-317.

Comment: @Samarth Did you fix the format specifier *and* remove the `&` before `F`?

Comment: yes i did that. and also as you said i changed the data type to double and kept the %e and ran the program. but the output is #QNAN0e+000

Comment: @Samarth No, don't change the data type.  Leave it as `long double` and change `%e` in the `printf` to `%Le`.

Comment: Yes sir i did that and the output is -2.000000e+000.

Comment: @Samarth I have changed your program according to dbush's instructions. It produces the correct/expected results. In short, make _no_ other changes other than the `printf` should be: `printf("The force is:-%Le", F);`

Comment: owww possibly MinGW related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296058/cant-print-correctly-a-long-double-in-c

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre yes i checked out the link you provided i think it might be the case.i use codelite on windows with mingw,any better alternatives to that are welcome.

Comment: I have edited the answer. it works (tested here)