# printf long double in cygwin GCC

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I am trying to printf a long double value in C, but it doesn't give the correct value. I have tried using different format parameters, but I'm not sure what to make of the output. I read from some other answers that it might be a problem with the compiler/OS, but I haven't managed to solve the problem.

I use cygwin GCC compiler on windows 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>
long double ans;

int main(){
    ans = 1.2457473567352;
    printf("long double ans = %.20Lf \n",ans);
}
```

The output:

```
long double ans = 0.000000000000000
long double ans = 1.133046674395481e-317
```

Comment: I tried it and it displays the good value. Your processor is 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: My cygwin is 64 bits, as well as windows

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001121.htm

Comment: My cygwin is 64 bits, as well as windows

Comment: Ok, because I know one similar case and the problem was the 32-bits processor. But now, I don't know if the problem come from Cygwin, but your code sounds good!

Comment: Code has 1 `printf()` call.  Out has 2 lines.  Please clarify, were 2 lines printed?

Comment: i also think the problem is with gcc ... this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296058/cant-print-correctly-a-long-double-in-c may help you

Comment: Are you linking in the math library?  Try adding some FP  math in `main()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double

Comment: Check the answer with the bounty in Artemy link.

Comment: as mentioned by @chux the printf code does not match with the output you show. It seems your are mixing different test codes. It works fine for me with cygwin gcc 6.4.0 `$ ./a 
long double ans = 1.24574735673519998436`