# long double gives wrong result when compiled with MinGW

Tags: c, double, mingw

When I change the *long double* type by *double* it works well. The thing is that I need more precision and I don't know why with a *long double* I have -1 as solution.

```
typedef long double big_num_t;
typedef unsigned int un_i;

long double suite(big_num_t x, big_num_t a2n_1, un_i n) {
    return ((-1) * ((a2n_1 * (2 * n - 1)) / (n * (2 * n + 1))) * (x * x));
}

int main() {
    big_num_t summ = 3;
    big_num_t temp = 3;
    for (un_i n = 1; n < 100; ++n) {
        temp = suite(3, temp, n);
        summ += temp;
    }
    summ *= (M_2_SQRTPI);
    printf("%Lf", summ);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: Compiling your example on my system with clang and gcc both yield `0.999978` not `-1`.

Comment: Note also that `long double` may have the same precision as `double`. This is true for Visual Studio, for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx

Comment: I also get 0.999978 on my system. Is this a print problem? Perhaps you could add: `if (summ < 0) printf("less zero") else printf("not less zero");` and see if this is consistent with the print of the value.

Comment: well, I using Clion on windows with MinGW. I switch now tu linux to see if it works better with gcc.

Comment: Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296058/cant-print-correctly-a-long-double-in-c

Comment: I think 4386427 has got the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than a double, wich is 8bytes, an array of int or char and create your own arithmethic for this type. This is the only way to be sure that you are capable of storing the number since this way you dont have to worry about number size, since in gcc at least, long double and double are both 8bytes, so both store the same number limits.

Comment: yeah I think your are right. the strange thing is that if I print the storage they have different values but is like that gcc or even minGW doesn't care and treat them like normal doubles. (is not a problem of printf function). thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tryed on linux with default gcc and the problem was similar. It looks like if you wanna use more precision you must use an extern library or implement yourself your aritmetic. Gmp lib is perfect for that. But it would be nice if C developpers or Iso or whatever choose a standard...