# Couldn't print a double long variable in C

Tags: c

I am a beginner, just learning C; I am trying to print a 'double long' variable. When I try to run the program, It produces incorrect output! Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double long x=10;
    printf("%.Lf",x);
    return 0;
}
/*
Output:
-0
Output in online compiler: 
10
*/
```

I use vs code with gcc. When I try to run the program, it displays wrong value. I tried using an online compiler, It works fine. Here is the online compiler I used:
https://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_gcc

Thanks.

edit: I tried using %Lf instead of %.Lf, but still the output is -0.000000

Comment: Why have a `.` in `"%.Lf"`?  Try `"%Lf\n"`

Comment: Rather than only desrcibe output, as in "it displays wrong value.", post the output seen _here_..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a similar problem with MinGW under Windows.

If you run the code with the extension `.cpp`, it'll show you the correct output.

However, to get the correct output in `c` , you can use **`__mingw_printf`** instead of `printf` while printing long double values.

Sample code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long double x=10;
    __mingw_printf("%Lf",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 10.000000

To know more, please check out the following resources:

- [Printing "long double" type via printf() on MinGW g++ 3.2.3](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/135253-printing-long-double-type-via-printf-mingw-g-3-2-3-a)
- [can't print correctly a long double in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296058/cant-print-correctly-a-long-double-in-c#answer-26307427)