# MinGW doesn't produce warnings

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw

I have successfully installed MinGW on a Windows 7 32bit machine, and have tried to compile a simple program using either the command line or the MinGW console.

The code has an intentional error in a printf statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main( void )
{
    printf("%d\n" , 3.14 ) ;
return 0 ;
}
```

The command `gcc -Wall hello.c` gives a correct warning: *hello.c:7:2: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int'...*

But the command `gcc -std=c99 -Wall hello.c` doesn't give any warning.

Both create an executable *a.exe* ( that runs and gives the same result ).

(Interestingly a command `gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall hello.c` gives the warning.)

I don't know if this is a bug, or did the installation go wrong somehow, but both seem unlikely since the compiler works and successfully compiled a larger project( but the  same warning of course omitted when using -std=c99 ).

I must be missing some information.

(ps: If someone has a new MinGW install, please test this.)

gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)

*Update 1:*

Defining `_GNU_SOURCE` before including `stdio.h` removes the warning even with  `gcc -Wall hello.c`.

*Update 2( might be less relevant ):*

Compiling

```
 printf("%lf\n" , 3.14 ) ;
```

`-std=c99` flag outputs: 0.000000

`-std=gnu99` outputs: 3.140000

And compiling:

```
 printf("%f\n" , 3.14 ) ;
```

`-std=gnu99` and `-std=c99` output: 3.140000

*Update 3:*

Functions that seem to be affected are: printf, fprintf, snprintf, sprintf.

Comment: What version? `gcc --version`

Comment: I get the same result (also 4.8.1). Someone should tell the developers because this seems like a bug to me.

Comment: What if you use -Wformat explicitly?

Comment: How about `-Wformat`?

Comment: @LarsLjung @ Shafik Yaghmour  No difference. I tried them all.

Comment: What happens if you `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before including `<stdio.h>` but compile as ISO C? Maybe the declarations for `printf` differ for GNU- and non-GNU C (and some annotation to the declaration is necessary to trigger the warning). Just a guess, though.

Comment: @mafso Well that is interesting. The warning disappeared with that define and `gcc -Wall hello.c`.

Comment: Can you preprocess the various combinations and grep for the `printf` declarations?

Comment: @mafso What do you mean? Every error that does and doesn't show? Every printf warning is completely ignored.

Comment: I wonder if `printf` is declared the same in `<stdio.h>` or maybe has some `__attribute__ (__format__ ...)` in one case but not the other. My GCC man page says, that `-Wformat` ambiguates certain `printf` versions (ISO C, with POSIX extensions, with GNU extensions, ...) for the warnings. I don't know how GCC knows which version is used, but maybe the declarations differ (or some macros are in action). `-E` runs only the preprocessor, `-E -dM` gives a list of defined macros. `(printf)(...)` would suppress macro expansion in case it is defined.

Comment: @mafso `static __inline__ __attribute__((__cdecl__)) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__))
int printf (const char *__format, ...)
{`...

Comment: For all combinations of `-std=[c|gnu][89]` with and without `#define _GNU_SOURCE`? And I'm quite surprised about a static function btw.

Comment: @mafso No warning from any -std=cXX and always a warning from -std=gnuXX.

Comment: Also, if `printf("%lf\n" , 3.14 );` results in anything but 3.14, that's a bug.

Comment: Actually mingw has more bugs and less features of Windows and new C and C++ standard supported compared to mingw64 and the development doesn't seem to progress much either http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#MinGW-w64

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thank you for the suggestion. MinGW-w64 doesn't suffer from these issues.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem with the lack of warning when using the `std=c99` option looks like it's because MinGW 4.8.1 preprocesses `stdio.h` a little different for the `printf()` family of functions when `-std=c99` is used compared to when `-std=gnu99` is used.

Note: I'm looking at MinGW 4.8.1 from TDM - I think other distributions might differ in these details.

MinGW has had some compatibility issues with formatting floating point values because of its historic reliance on `msvcrt.dll` for the C runtime and the fact that MSVC uses a 64-bit representation for `long double` while gcc uses a 96-bit (or 128-bit on x64) representation.  See [gcc: printf and long double leads to wrong output. [C - Type conversion messes up]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134547/gcc-printf-and-long-double-leads-to-wrong-output-c-type-conversion-messes-u) for some details.  More recent versions of MinGW have provided thier own implementation of the `printf()` family of functions (with a `__mingw_` prefix on the name) in `libmingwex.a` to solve those problems.

The header files `_mingw.h` and `stdio.h` configure whether or not the `libmingwex.a` implementations or the `msvcrt.dll` implementations will be used.

It appears that if ANSI compliance is requested, MinGW will use the `libmingwex.a` implementations (there are a number of other ways to get this configuration too - look at the headers for details). Wiring up a user call to `printf()` to the `__mingw_printf()` implementation in `libmingwex.a` is done by `stdio.h` defining a static inline implementation of `printf()` that is a thin wrapper around a call to `__mingw_vfprintf()`.  Apparently the `-Wformat` doesn't get applied to versions of `printf()` family functions that the compiler doesn't believe to be part of the library (a reasonable assumption - the compiler doesn't really know anything about those functions).  This problem can be fixed by applying the appropriate function attribute (for example: `__attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)))`) to the static inline wrapper functions.

The other problem you found, where `printf("%lf\n", 3.14)` prints `0.000000` when using `std=c99`, looks to be a bug in the `libmingwex.a` implementation of `__mingw_vfprintf()`. It seems that `__mingw_vfprintf()` mistakenly interprets `"%lf"` to mean the argument is a `long double`. I'm not too surprised by that - I always have to look up whether `%lf` means `double` or `long double`.

Comment: Very well. I'll quote from the C standard, since I can see you're used to that. ["f,F   A double argument representing a floating-point number ..."](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8)

Comment: It's not really possible to pass a `float` to `printf()` because an argument of that type is promoted to `double`.  I suppose that`"%lf"` and `"%f"` are equivalent so format strings with them can 'echo' their use in `scanf()`.  But I'm not sure what these recent comments are about - the answer says that it appears that `__mingw_vfprintf()` might be mistakenly treating `"%lf"` as using a `long double` argument since it apparently produces different output for `"%lf"` and `"%f"` specifications.  It doesn't say that `"%lf"` should be used with a `long double` type.

Comment: The `l` in `%lf` is explicitly ignored - `%f` alone covers the use of `double` and `float` (the latter being down-converted). It's there to provide comfort to those who think it's required as `l` is in `%ld` for long ints.