# Unexpected output when printing the value of an integer

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, compiler-errors

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int i = 5;
   printf("%p",i);
}
```

I tried to compile this program on Linux using GCC compiler which on compilation of the program issues a warning saying

```
%p expects a void* pointer
```

and when run gives an output of 46600x3.

But when I compile it online using the site codingground.tutorialspoint.com I get an output
equals `0x5`  i.e. a hexadecimal output, can anyone please explain the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%p` expects the address of something(or a pointer). You provide the value of the variable `i` instead of the address. Use

```
printf("%p",(void*)&i);
```

instead of

```
printf("%p",i);
```

and GCC will compile the program without warnings and it will print the address where `i` is stored when you run it. The ampersand(`&`) is the address-of operator and it gives the address of the variable. The cast is also neccessary as the format specifier `%p` expects an argument of type `void*` whereas `&i` is of type `int*`.

---

If you want the value of the variable to be printed,use

```
printf("%d",i);
```

Using the wrong format specifier will lead to [UB(Undefined Behavior)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: `p` requires a `(void *)` argument. You have to use `printf("%p", (void *) &i);`

Comment: @ouah ,GCC does not give any warnings without the cast. Also,I get the same output if I had/had not added the cast. Is the cast compulsory?

Comment: gcc warns with `-pedantic`, and yes the cast is required.

Comment: @ouah Sources, please.

Comment: @ouah , No. Even with `-pedantic`,GCC does not emit any error or warning

Comment: @Qid Pointers are not "`void *` by nature". The cast is required. `int *` and `void *` are not guaranteed by the Standard to have same size or representation. For `p` conversion specifier, read C11, 7.21.6.1p8 "p The argument shall be a pointer to void". You are violating a shall -> undefined behavior.

Comment: @CoolGuy try with `-Wall -pedantic`

Comment: @ouah , Nothing. I compiled with `gcc filename -o blah -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic`

Comment: @ouah Huh, interesting.

Comment: @Qix , You can [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/printfp-and-casting-to-void)

Comment: @CoolGuy I blame your test case, at least all gcc recent versions warn with `-Wall -pedantic`.

Comment: @ouah , My GCC version is 4.8.1. Ok.You are right. I [tested it on an online compiler](http://rextester.com/runcode) and it gives a warning. Why is it not emitting a warning for me??

Comment: @ouah , Got the problem. When I use `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` or `-std=c89` or do not have an `-std` flag, there is no warning whereas when I use `-std=gnu89` or `-std=gnu99` or `-std=gnu11` ,GCC emits a warning. Why is it like that?

Comment: @CoolGuy I got warning with `-std=c99` with both gcc 4.7.1 and 4.8.2.

Comment: @CoolGuy: MinGW? Maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363795/mingw-doesnt-produce-warnings

Comment: @mafso , [I think so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755356/gcc-does-not-emit-a-warning-when-compiling)..

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("%p",i);
```

Using wrong format specifier will lead to undefined behavior. `%p` expects the arguement of type `void *` in your case you are passing the value of `i` and not the address in order to print out the address you should pass `&i`

You should use

```
printf("%d",i);
```

to print the integer value of `i`

The code should be like

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int i = 5;
   printf("%d",i); /* To print value of i */
   printf("%p",(void *)&i); /* Address of variable i */
}
```

Comment: `p` requires a `(void *)` argument. You have to use `printf("%p", (void *) &i);`

Comment: @ouah Yes i have mentioned that in my answer casting `void *` looks redundant though don't you feel so?

Comment: The cast in `printf("%p",(void *)&i);` is not redundant, it is required as `&i` is not of type `void *`.