# GCC does not emit a warning when compiling

Tags: c, gcc, gnu

The following code compiles and runs but I expect a warning when compiling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

  int x = 10;
  printf("%p\n",&x);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GCC,from an online compiler](http://rextester.com/XWFD3742) with command line argument

```
-Wall -std=gnu99 -O2 -o a.out source_file.c -pedantic -Wextra
```

gives out the following warning when compiling

```
source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
source_file.c:7:3: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%p\n",&x);
```

because I've not added a `(void*)` cast before `&x` as `%p` expects an argument of type `void*`
 .But when I compile using

```
gcc SO.c -o so -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11
```

or

```
gcc SO.c -o so -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99
```

or

```
gcc SO.c -o so -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c89
```

GCC(in my PC) does **not** give out a warning whereas compiling(again in my PC) using

```
gcc SO.c -o so -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11
```

or

```
gcc SO.c -o so -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu99
```

or

```
gcc SO.c -o so -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu89
```

or

```
gcc SO.c -o so -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

I get the warning mentioned above. Why is it like that? My GCC version is 4.8.1 and I'm using Windows. I compile from the console,i.e, `cmd`.

Comment: Is it mingw gcc, cygwin gcc or something else?

Comment: @ouah , I don't know it exactly,but using `gcc -v` shows `Target: mingw32`. So I guess its mingw gcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it like that?

First, I can also reproduce this inconsistent state with mingw32 gcc 4.8.1 on my machine.

While the diagnostic is not required (no constraint violation) by the C Standard, there is no reason gcc issues the diagnostic with `-std=gnu11` and not with `-std=c11`.

Moreover with gcc 4.8.2 on Linux on my machine, the diagnostic appears with both `-std=c11` and `-std=gnu11`.

So it looks like a bug in gcc (either in gcc 4.8.1 or in mingw32 gcc 4.8.1).

Comment: I'll assume mingw lacks an  `__attribute__((format(printf,3,4)))` in the stdio header files of mingw on the printf() declaration - without that, printf is just a normal varadic function, and no format checking can be provided by -Wformat

Comment: @nos could be but gcc documentation of format attribute says that *The compiler always (unless -ffreestanding or -fno-builtin is used) checks formats for the standard library functions printf, [...] whenever such warnings are requested (using -Wformat), so there is no need to modify the header file stdio.h* so it seems even without the attribute gcc should warn.

Comment: @ouah , Is this question related to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363795/mingw-doesnt-produce-warnings)?

Comment: @CoolGuy nice catch, yes it seems so and I think your question should be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for both [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Other-Output-Conversions.html#Other-Output-Conversions) and C99 libc (page 315 of the [pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) explicitly says that the argument for `%p` conversion "must be of type `void *`".

The fact that the warning is not issued should be a particularity of what your compiler thinks about Cxx standards. A stock gcc 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 issues the warning for all the six standards mentioned in your post.