# Is there something wrong with the way I am using a long double?

Tags: c++

I have recently become interested in learning about programming in c++, because I want to get a bit deeper understanding of the way computers work and handle instructions. I thought I would try out the data types, but I don't really understand what's happening with my output...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    float fValue = 123.456789;
    cout << setprecision(20) << fixed << fValue << endl;
    cout << "Size of float: " << sizeof(float) << endl;

    double dValue = 123.456789;
    cout << setprecision(20) << fixed << dValue << endl;
    cout << "Size of double: " << sizeof(double) << endl;

    long double lValue = 123.456789;
    cout << setprecision(20) << fixed << lValue << endl;
    cout << "Size of long double: " << sizeof(long double) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output I expected would be something like:

```
123.45678710937500000000
Size of float: 4
123.45678900000000000000
Size of double: 8
123.45678900000000000000
Size of long double: 16
```

This is my actual output:

```
123.45678710937500000000
Size of float: 4
123.45678900000000000000
Size of double: 8
-6518427077408613100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00000000000000000000
Size of long double: 12
```

Any ideas on what happened would be much appreciated, thanks!

Edit:

```
System:
Windows 10 Pro Technical Preview
64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
Eclipse CDT 8.5
```

[image: MinGW Installation]

Comment: Can't reproduce. What compiler are you using?

Comment: The size of `long double` varies by compiler and hardware.  Sizes 8, 12, and 16 are known.  What you're seeing as a size is perfectly reasonable, even if it wasn't what you expected.  The formatted output is not so reasonable, though.

Comment: FWIW (which is approximately nothing), running your code on Mac OS X 10.10.2 with GCC 4.9.1 yields: `123.45678710937500000000
Size of float: 4
123.45678900000000055570
Size of double: 8
123.45678900000000055570
Size of long double: 16`.  Adding the `F` suffix to the `float` value and the `L` suffix to the `long double` value makes no difference to `float` or `double` output, but changes the `long double` output to: `123.45678900000000000059
Size of long double: 16`, which shows better accuracy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I would expect that the OP is on a 32-bit system, try `-m32`.

Comment: @remyabel I am running Windows 10,  with Eclipse CDT 8.5.0 Luna

Comment: @remyabel:  Curious why you think the OP is on a 32-bit system?

Comment: @remyabel I am on a 64-bit system

Comment: @remyabel: Interesting thought, but it makes no difference on Mac OS X.  I checked with `file longdbl` (the name of the testing program) and got the result 
`longdbl: Mach-O executable i386`, but it produced the same output as the 64-bit version.

Comment: Edited the info in my post, I hope that makes it more clear, let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Win64 with the MinGW 32 toolchain, with g++ version 4.7.1

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7136886/12711 for some details on what you're probably running into. tl;dr version: MinGW GCC uses a different binary type than the msvcrt runtime that MinGW relies on.  This has been fixed in more recent versions of MinGW, but I don't know the details of the exact versions/distributions that have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

From the [patch that fixed this in earlier versions](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20130930/090167.html):

> MinGW uses the Microsoft runtime DLL msvcrt.dll. Here lies a problem: while gcc creates 80 bits long doubles, the MS runtime accepts 64 bit long doubles only.

This bug happens to me when I use 4.8.1 revision 4 from MinGW-get (the most recent version it offers), but not when I use 4.8.1 revision 5.

So you are not using long double wrong (although there would be better accuracy to do `long double lValue = 123.456789L` to make sure it doesn't take 123.456789 as a double, then cast it to a long double).

The easiest way to fix this would be to simply change the version of MinGW you are using to 4.9 or 4.7, depending on what you need (you can get 4.9 [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.1/)).

If you are willing to instead use printf, you could change to `printf("%Lf", ...)`, and either:

- add the flag -posix when you compile with g++
- add `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` before `#include <cstdio>` (found this from the [origional patch](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20130930/090167.html))

Finally, you can even just cast to a `double` whenever you try to print out the `long double` (there is some loss of accuracy, but it shouldn't matter when just printing out numbers).

To find more details, you can also look at [my blog post on this issue](http://www.diusrex.com/2015/05/long-double-bug-in-mingw/).

Update: If you want to continue to use Mingw 4.8, you can also just [download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) a different distribution of Mignw, which didn't have that problem for me.