# Arithmetic double expression and c/c++

Tags: c, math, double, expression, precision

Why this code give me 2 different result on ris1 and ris2?

Why they are not equivalent???

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double x1 = 0.4628471891711442;
    double h = 0.51152525298500628;
    double lambda = 0.99999999999999989;
    double t = 0.10000000000000001;
    double ris1 = 0;
    double ris2 = 0;

    ris1 = x1 - (h * exp(-lambda * t));

    double sub = h * exp(-lambda * t);
    ris2 = x1 - sub;

    printf("\n\nris1 = %1.4e", ris1);
    printf("\n\nris2 = %1.4e", ris2);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
ris1 = 8.9257e-017

ris2 = 1.1102e-016
```

I am working with mingw in eclipse.
Here my mingw installed framework: http://ctrlv.in/638751

Comment: Is this all the code? I don't think it is, and the problem has to be somewhere else. Because this code as it is has no problems. Have you tried to test the code in an isolated compilation unit? Note that none of those two values is correct. The answer is `5.5511e-17`.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the environment in which you run your code? I am unable to reproduce your problem. In particular I would like you to post the version of your standard libraries, the compiler and all the options (especially optimization-related) used for compilation, as well as the data about processor which ran the code.

Comment: I am using mingw and eclipse

Comment: And c++ although your code is c. There is no way to reproduce your problem. Try to run the program directly in a console window.

Comment: I have generated the .exe and it gives me the some results

Comment: @mszymborski in the pasted link you can find my mingw configuration from  the installation manager.

Comment: Essentially, you are computing the difference between two floating point values that are very close in value (i.e. difference is near zero).   That is one way to amplify the effects of rounding error, and increase sensitivity to order of operations.

Comment: @Peter - it has nothing to do with it. Using a proper implementation (see my answer) the only possible difference could be casting a 80-bit value used in computations to a 64-bit value for storage and then promoting it back and using it in the subtraction. Other than that, the errors should propagate the same way in both expressions.

Comment: @iharob: The code is C++, as OP included `<iostream>` and uses `namespace` which do not exist in C.

Comment: @Olaf There is nothing in the code that makes it invalid c except for that and it's not used anywhere. I suspect that the OP does not know the difference.

Comment: @iharob: I did not say different;-) Question is how to treat such a situation (neither the first one, nor the last). As there is no clear problem statement and the error is likely due to rounding, I think it can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Given your configuration, it's most likely  a bug in implementation of MinGW's g++ 4.8.1-4 , as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523892/is-there-something-wrong-with-the-way-i-am-using-a-long-double/29218355#29218355). Please consider updating (or downgrading) your MinGW installation..

Comment: Or even avoiding MinGW and using an operating system where the bug does not exist for g++. Or using MSVC c++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The difference of `x1 - sub` is near the last few bits of `double` precision as the 2 variables are about the same value.  [@peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673508/arithmetic-double-expression-and-c-c/32674880#comment53193619_32673508)

Due to optimization and the degree of correctness  of `exp()`, slightly variant answers are expected.

Another factor is C allows `double` math to be carried out as `double` or `long double` depending on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

These 2 above may not be used equally with the different computation paths.

By forcing extra precision with `long double`, the answers are consistent

```
ris1 = 1.2357e-16
ris2 = 1.2357e-16
```