# Ansi C: Long Double Variable Printing Out to a Value of 0.000000

Tags: c, ansi-c

When I run the Ansi C program below, a value of "0.000000" is printed out. Does anyone know why the value "561.308000" is not being printed out? I am using Dev-C++ to run the program, and the compiler I am using is: Mingw port of GCC (GNU Compiler Collection), version MSVCRT 2.95.2-1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    long double x = 561.308;
    printf("%Lf",x);
}
```

Comment: It works well on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QDKLzZcAw0x57l4B). What is your compiler?

Comment: it works good in [ideone](http://ideone.com/WiZu2D).

Comment: I am using Dev-C++5.11.

Comment: Dev-C++ is an editor. What is your **compiler**? Please also include the version of your compiler.

Comment: I use Mingw port of GCC (GNU Compiler Collection), version MSVCRT 2.95.2-1, as my compiler.

Comment: `-0.000000` is printed on Dev-C++ 5.11 and gcc (GCC) 4.8.1

Comment: This is implementation specific behavior. Saying you're using GCC isn't saying what version of GCC, but as MikeCAT noticed, at least we know 4.8.1 is showing -0.000.... There are a huge range of potential issues. Microsoft's C runtime doesn't support 80 bit floating point numbers (haven't checked very recent versions though), which means they map long double to double sometimes. The long double specifier should not be considered very portable because of this. __mingw_printf is a version that might help

Comment: A better way of expressing what @JVene seems to be saying is that your compiler and libc ("C runtime") probably disagree on what `long double` is. mingw is a mess like this...

Comment: Using `printf("%Le",x);` or `printf("%La",x);` would provide more info.

Comment: `561.308` is double. To get long double use [`561.308L`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21557816/995714)

Comment: long double in gcc is 80-bit extended precision type, but mingw uses MSVC's CRT library which doesn't support that type. So you must use mingw64 or some other workarounds

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Mingw64 won't solve it, same issue.

Comment: The fix is available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28523892/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Compiling with `gcc (GCC) 4.8.1` on Windows 7 64bit with this command is worked. (Add `-std=c99` to the option to have the compiler work with C99)

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 test.c -o test.exe`

Comment: Why would C99 make a difference? As far as I know, `long double` was already allowed in C90.

Comment: And indeed, this doesn't work on Mingw 64 gcc 4.9.1. Prints zero.

Answer (score 0):

the zero might be the return value of the main()
it is printed
Could you try :

```
printf("Answer is : %Lf",x);
```

to see whether you got 0.000000 or Answer is: 0.0000

And how about

```
printf("Answer is : %Lf", 561.38888);
```

I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    long double x = 561.308;
    printf("%Lf",x);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The value that was printed out when I tried your first suggestion was: Answer is : 0.000000

Comment: The value that was printed out when I tried your second suggestion was: Answer is : 561.388880

Comment: @Spacedog789 could you try the code I uploaded?

Comment: I compiled your uploaded code and ran it. This is what was printed out: 0.000000