# C - long double and printf issue

Tags: c, printf, long-double

I am new C programmer and I am working on a school project where I have to approximate the value or pi. My professor stated that we have to declare all integer terms using `long double`. The console shows me asking the user for the number of terms to approximate pi given a function. I enter 1 for the number of terms however the code returns -0.00000000 instead of 4.00000000.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long double approx1(int terms)
{
    long double pi = 0;
    long double num = 4;
    long double denom = 1;
    int i;

    for(i=1; i <= terms; i++)
    {
        if(i%2 != 0)
        {
            pi=pi+(num/denom);
        }
        else
        {
            pi=pi-(num/denom);
        }
        denom = denom + 2;
    }
     printf("%.8Lf\n", pi);
}

int main()
{
    int terms;
    long double pie;

    printf("input number of terms, input 0 to cancel\n");
    scanf("%d", &terms);

    while(terms != 0)
    {
        if(terms > 0)
        {
            pie = approx1(terms);
            printf("%.8Lf\n", pie);
            printf("GG mate\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Incorrect input, please enter a correct input\n");
            scanf("%d", &terms);
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't had any success in getting it to work( it works with float though). What am I doing wrong? (I am using Code Blocks with the included compiler btw.)

Comment: "all integer terms using `long double`" `long double` is not an integer type. What do you mean?

Comment: If your Code::Blocks IDE is using the MinGW GCC compiler (which I believe is common), you might also be running into this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7136886/12711  I believe that newer versions of MinGW solve the problem by implementing custom support for `printf()` instead of relying only on using `msvcrt.dll`.  So you might want to try a newer version of MinGW or MinGW-w64.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to add a `return` statement in your `approx1()` function. Withoout that `return` statement, if you make use of the returned value, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.9.1

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.