# Program that is supposed to print the value of n! (n entered by the user) behaves strangely with long doubles in C

Tags: c, factorial, long-double

I'm currently testing the maximum values of n! where n is a positive integer entered by the user. I tested this with:

- short
- int
- long
- long long
- float
- double

---

With all of the above types the program prints the correct value. However, when I declare factorial to be of type long double, the program behaves strangely. For example, I enter 10!, the program outputs -21340077980675728 with ~50 zeros after the 8, which is obviously not correct. So where's my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i;
    long double factorial = 1.0;

    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf(" %d", &n);

    for (i = n; i >= 1; i--){
        factorial *= i;
    }
    printf("Factorial of %d: %.0Lf\n", n, factorial);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which system are you using.

Comment: If you are using MINGW, see this link: https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/135253-printing-long-double-type-via-printf-mingw-g-3-2-3-a

Comment: More for MINGW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997258/strange-unsigned-long-long-int-behaviour/5997384#5997384

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134547/gcc-printf-and-long-double-leads-to-wrong-output-c-type-conversion-messes-u

Comment: Check the `sizeof` long double. If it is 8 then the compiler does not have a separate long double type. You'd better off using `unsigned long long` as it guarantees at least 64 bits of *integer* precision

Comment: In any case, on x86, the long double would *maximally* have only the same precision as `unsigned long long`, and possibly less...