# Displaying very large number

Tags: c, long-integer, unsigned

As we know that 4294967295 is the largest number in `unsigned int` if I multiply this number by itself then how to display it? I have tried:

```
long unsigned int NUMBER = 4294967295 * 4294967295;
```

but still getting 1 as answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you printf an unsigned long long int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-printf-an-unsigned-long-long-int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an overflow. Consider the muplication in hexadecimal:

```
0xffffffff * 0xffffffff == 0xfffffffe00000001
                                     ^^^^^^^^
                                     only the last 32 bits are returned
```

The solution is to use a larger type such as `long long unsigned`:

```
long long unsigned int NUMBER = 4294967295ULL * 4294967295ULL;
```

The suffix `ULL` means `unsigned long long`.

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Y4E4U)

Comment: thanks sir but if my number is store in integer like unsigned      unsigned long int num =4294967295 ;then

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication overflows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 4294967295;
    unsigned int b = 4294967295;

    // force to perform multiplication based on larger type than unsigned int
    unsigned long long NUMBER = (unsigned long long)a * b;
    printf("%llu\n", NUMBER);
}
```

Comment: thanks sir but if my number is store in integer like unsigned unsigned long int num =4294967295 ;then

Answer (score 0):

You state in your question that you know max int is equal to 4294967295. That means that you can't store a number larger than that if you are using unsigned int.

C longs store up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 when unsigned on a 64 bit unix system <sup>[[source]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_integer#CommonSizes)</sup> so you need only suffix your numbers with UL : `4294967295UL`

If you aren't using a 64-bit unix system then you should use `long long unsigned int` and suffix with `LL`

Comment: thanks alot sir  
thanks sir but if my number is store in integer like unsigned unsigned long int num =4294967295 ;then

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's an overflow. If you are using c, there isn't any easy way to do such big number multiply as i knew. Maybe you need write one by yourself. In fact some language support such features originally.