# printf("%u\n",4294967296) output 0 with a warning on ubuntu server 11.10 for i386

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu

On ubuntu server 11.10 for i386, `sizeof(int)` is 4, so I guess `4294967296` is the maximum number for int type, isn't it? But `printf("%u\n",4294967296)` output 0 with a warning :

> warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but
>   argument 2 has type 'long long unsigned int' [-Wformat]

Any suggestion ?

The version of gcc is  (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1

Answer (score 9):

4294967296 is exactly 2^32, which is 1 **beyond** the maximum supported by **`unsigned`** `int` (assuming 32-bit).  So C treats that integer literal as if it were of the next integer type that can represent it (`long long int`).  (I'm not sure why the warning complains that it's `long long unsigned int`).

You've therefore invoked undefined behaviour by providing a mismatch between your format specifier and the argument types (in practice, you're simply seeing modulo wrap-around).

Change your format specifier to `"%llu\n"`.

Comment: Sorry, `printf("%lu\n", 4294967296 )` gives a waring `warning: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'long long int' [-Wformat]` and output 0

Answer (score 3):

You can use the constants in [limits.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/) to determine the maximum possible and minimum possible values for various types for your implementation. Try

```
printf("%u\n", UINT_MAX);
```

and you'll find that the output is:

```
4294967295
```

But you are asking `printf()` to print 4294967296 which is beyond the maximum possible unsigned integer for your implementation.

The value of `UINT_MAX` makes sense since you have told us that `sizeof (int)` is 4. The maximum possible 4-byte integer or 32-bit integer is 111111111 111111111 111111111 111111111 when expressed in binary or FFFFFFFF when expressed in hexadecimal or 4294967295 when expressed in decimal.

You have got two ways to fix this code. A simple way is:

```
printf("%llu\n", 4294967296ull);
```

A more portable way to fix this by using the ISO C99 standard is:

```
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", (uint64_t) 4294967296);
```

For the latter, you need to `#include <inttypes.h>`.

Comment: Excuse me, Where is the `UINT_MAX`  ?

Comment: `#include <limits.h>` - I have mentioned it in the last paragraph of my response.

Comment: `printf("%llu\n", 4294967296);` is not portable.  If `long` is 64 bits, then `4294967296` is of type `long`, which is incompatible with `"%llu"`.  You could use `printf("%llu\n",4294967296ULL);`.  Or, for this particular case, `puts("4294967296");`

Comment: Keith Thompson, I agree. I have incorporated your suggestion in my response.

Comment: +1: These solutions are better than what I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The type of an unsuffixed integer literal such as `4294967296` depends on the value of the literal and the ranges of the predefined types for the implementation.

The type of a decimal constant is the first of:

- `int`
- `long int`
- `long long int`

(Octal and hexadecimal literals can be of unsigned types; see section 6.4.4.1 of [the C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) for details.)

in which its value can be represented exactly.  The language requires that `int` is at least 16 bits, `long int` is at least 32 bits, and `long long int` is at least 64 bits, but each can be wider.

On your system (Ubuntu, 32 bits, same as mine), `int` and `long int` are both 32 bits, and `long long int` is 64 bits, so `4294967296` is of type `long long int`.  (The message you showed us indicates that it's `long long unsigned int`, which doesn't seem right; are you sure that's the message you got for that specific code?)

The behavior of calling `printf` with an argument of a type that's inconsistent with the format is undefined.  You probably got `9` as output because the value passed was `0x0000000100000000`, and `printf` happened to use the low-order 32 bits of the 64-bit value.  Other behaviors are possible.

You ask for "Any suggestion", but it's not clear from your question what you want to do.  A way to produce the output you probably expected is:

```
puts("4294967296");
```

but I'm sure that's not the kind of answer you're looking for.

Usually when you print a number with `printf`, the argument will be a variable rather than a literal, and the type will be determined by the declared type of the variable.  Or it might be a more complicated expression, in which case the type is determined by the types of the operands; if they're of different types, there's a moderately complicated set of rules that determine what the final result is.  Just make sure the format you use corresponds to the (promoted) type of the argument.

If you have a more specific question, we'll be glad to give a more specific answer.

Comment: Minor nitpick: The type of a decimal constant _without suffix_ is the first of ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want do do it in a portable way take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679/540286).