# Printing unsigned long long int Value Type Returns Strange Results

Tags: c, syntax, printf, unsigned-long-long-int

I have a problem while using the `printf` function to print values of type `unsigned long long int`

I have no idea what's wrong. I'm using Dev-Cpp 4.9.9.2 and Visual Studio 2010 Professional (I know that it's not C compiler, but anyway, wanted to try) on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. For displaying, I used `%llu` modifier (according to [How do you printf an unsigned long long int(the format specifier for unsigned long long int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-printf-an-unsigned-long-long-int)) but I also tried I64d with no effect...

---

Firstly, I just wanted to print minimum and maximum value of `unsigned long long int` (using `ULONG_MAX` from `limits.h`)

```
printf("unsigned long long int: \n%llu to %llu \n\n", 0, ULONG_MAX);
```

Returns:

> unsigned long long int: 18446744069414584320 to 1580552164021 *(Dev-Cpp)*
>
> unsigned long long int: 18446744069414584320 to 0 *(Visual Studio)*

---

Then I tried to using `printf` to print two zeros

```
printf("unsigned long long int: \n%llu to %llu \n\n", 0, 0);
```

Returns:

> unsigned long long int:
>   0 to 1580552164021 *(Dev-Cpp)*
>
> unsigned long long int: 0 to 0 *(Visual Studio)*

---

Also tried two `ULONG_MAX` values

```
printf("unsigned long long int: \n%llu to %llu \n\n", ULONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX);
```

Returns:

> unsigned long long int: 18446744073709551615 to 1580552164021 *(Dev-Cpp)*
>
> unsigned long long int:
>   18446744073709551615 to 0 *(Visual Studio)*

---

Why does it behave like that? Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
printf("unsigned long long int: \n%llu to %llu \n\n", 0, ULONG_MAX);
```

You use a `unsigned long long` format specifier, but you pass an `int` and an `unsigned long` value.  Promotion rules mean you can be sloppy for everything `int`-sized or smaller, which does *not* apply to `long long`.

Use casts:

```
printf("unsigned long long int: \n%llu to %llu \n\n",
       0ULL, (unsigned long long) ULONG_MAX);
```

**Explanation:** When passing arguments to `printf`, any type that can fit in an `int` is promoted to `int`, and then any type that can fit in an `unsigned int` is promoted to `unsigned int`.  It is also okay to pass an unsigned type to a signed format specifier or vice versa as long as the *value* passed can be represented using the type specified by the format specifier.

So you must be careful with `long` and `long long`, but you can be sloppy with `int`, `short`, and `char`.

**Most compilers** have settings to make them warn you about this type of error, since it can be detected at compile-time fairly easily; GCC and Clang have `-Wformat` which results in the following warnings:

```
test.c:5: warning: format ‘%llu’ expects type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
test.c:5: warning: format ‘%llu’ expects type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’
```

Answer (score 10):

You are not passing `unsigned long longs`. You are passing an `int` (0) and `unsigned long` (ULONG_MAX). You must pass to `printf()` exactly what you promise to pass in the format string.

Try this instead:

```
printf("unsigned long long int: \n%llu to %llu \n\n", 0ULL, (unsigned long long)ULONG_MAX);
```

Answer (score 4):

`ULONG_MAX` refers to `unsigned long` and not to `unsigned long long`. For the latter, use `ULLONG_MAX` (note the extra `L`).

You need to change the `printf()` calls like so:

```
printf("unsigned long long int: \n%llu to %llu \n\n", 0ULL, ULLONG_MAX);
printf("unsigned long long int: \n%llu to %llu \n\n", ULLONG_MAX, ULLONG_MAX);
```

This ensures that the arguments to `printf()` match the format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

long long int is a type from the C99 standard, MSVC doesn't support this. Take a compiler with C99 support (like MinGW for Windows) and it will work.

Comment: MSVC does support `long long` despite not supporting C99 fully.