# Unsigned Long Long - weird output

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc, g++

OK, I'm trying to print the decimal/hexadecimal version of a relatively big `unsigned long long` and the results I'm getting are quite weird...

**The code :**

```
unsigned long long a = 1llu<<63;

printf("decimal = %llu\n",a);
printf("hexadecimal = %llx\n",a);
```

**The output :**

```
decimal = 9223372036854775808
hexadecimal = 8000000000000000
```

---

Now, here's what :

- The hexadecimal output **is** correct.
- The decimal output is **not** (should be `9223372036854780000`)

Why's that happening? What am I doing wrong???

Comment: 2^63 is what it prints. I see no problem here.

Comment: Possible duplicate? Interesting though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-printf-an-unsigned-long-long-int

Comment: @chris Really??? I don't think it even fits a 64-bit integer, does it? And if so, why?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon, An unsigned 64-bit integer can hold up to 2^64 - 1. This is 2^63.

Comment: @chris I stand corrected. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since five is not a factor of any power of two, no power of two ends in zero. Your other source which gave `9223372036854780000` is incorrect.

Comment: My other source is Mac OS X's Programmer's calculator. But, yep, your mathematical point of view definitely makes sense.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Punching "1 << 63" gives a number ending in 808. Using the scientific calculator's 2^x button for 2^63 then switching to programmer mode results in 9,223,372,036,854,776,000. Not sure exactly what you did.

Comment: I'm really confused. Just switched to `Programmer` view. `1` `X<<Y` `63`. And it still outputs the wrong value. - The thing is the binary display (under the main calculator box) shows the number as it should be.

Comment: Congratulations, you have found a bug in the Mac calculator.

Comment: Mac calculator is probably computing with double precision floating point math, and using a low-quality print-to-decimal algorithm that cannot produce the exact value (note that the exact value **is** representable in IEEE double).