# unsigned long long type printing in hexadecimal format

Tags: c, integer, printf

I am trying to print out an `unsigned long long` like this:

```
  printf("Hex add is: 0x%ux ", hexAdd);
```

but I am getting type conversion errors since I have an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you printf an unsigned long long int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-printf-an-unsigned-long-long-int)

Comment: For the specific format you're looking for, with the `0x` prefix, use `"0x%llx"`.

Comment: @Joseph It is not a perfect duplicate of that question. Here the OP wants to output in hex format, not in decimal.

Comment: Sure, Lorenzo, now that you've edited the question to supply information OP did not make clear when asked.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use the same `ll` size modifier for `%x`, thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long long x = 123456789012345ULL;
    printf("%llx\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

The full range of conversion and formatting specifiers is in a great table here:

- [`printf` documentation on cppeference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Answer (score 8):

try `%llu` - this will be long long unsigned in decimal form

`%llx` prints long long unsigned in hex

Comment: But `printf("%llu\n", (long long unsigned int) 243);` prints `243`, which is decimal, not hex; `printf("%llx\n", (long long unsigned int) 243);` prints `f3` in hex.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("Hex add is: %llu", hexAdd);
```

Comment: But I want the hex version of it, hence the reason for using x in the first place.

Comment: In that case, use `%llx` but I'm assuming by your second comment you figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with this using the MinGW libraries. I couldn't get it to recognize the %llu or %llx stuff.

Here is my answer...

```
void PutValue64(uint64_t value) {
char    a_string[25];   // 16 for the hex data, 2 for the 0x, 1 for the term, and some spare
uint32  MSB_part;
uint32  LSB_part;

    MSB_part = value >> 32;
    LSB_part= value & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;

    printf(a_string, "0x%04x%08x", MSB_part, LSB_part);
}
```

Note, I think the %04x can simply be %x, but the %08x is required.

Good luck.
Mark