# format specifier for signed long long type printing in hexadecimal format in c

Tags: c

what is the format specifier for signed long long type and unsigned long long type printing in hexa decimal format in c.
I want to learn how to print format specifier for signed long long type and unsigned long long type printing in hexa decimal format in c.

Comment: @mrun Not a duplicate since it doesn't address hex.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah my bad, I meant this one [unsigned long long type printing in hexadecimal format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284978/unsigned-long-long-type-printing-in-hexadecimal-format) but got confused by Joseph's comment.

Answer (score 3):

"Signed" and "unsigned" do not really apply to hexadecimal, since it's typically just a convenient representation of a bit pattern rather than an actual numerical value, and therefore implicitly unsigned. So for an `unsigned long long` you would just use `%llx` (or `%#llx` if you want the `0x` prefix).

Comment: (Or you could just write `0x%llx`... the `#` conversion specifier for hex ought to be one of the most pointless features of C.)