# Pascal's Triangle in C

Tags: c, largenumber, pascals-triangle

I'm a computer engineering student and next semester I am going to start C course. So in order to prepare myself a bit, I have started learning C by myself and stumbled across an interesting task, designed for, how it seemed to me at first sight, not a very advanced level.

The task is to write a program to compute the value of a given position in **Pascal's Triangle**. And the formula given to compute it is written as **element = row! / ( position! * (row - position)! )**

I've written a simple console program that seems to work okay, until I get to testing it with **large** numbers.

When trying this program with row 16 and position 3, it calculates the value as 0, although it's obvious that there can't be such a value (in fact it should compute the value as 560), all cells of this triangle are supposed to be integers and be greater than one.

I suppose I'm experiencing a problem with **storing and processing large numbers**. The factorial function seems to work okay, and the formula I used works until I get to trying large numbers

So far the best solution was found here - [How do you printf an unsigned long long int(the format specifier for unsigned long long int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-printf-an-unsigned-long-long-int)  using inttypes.h library with type uint64_t but it still doesn't give me the result I need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void clear_input(void);
uint64_t factorial(int x);

int main()
{
    // Printing
    printf("This program computes the value of a given position in Pascal's Triangle.\n");
    printf("You will be asked for row and position of the value.\n");
    printf("Note that the rows and positions starts from 0.\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("     1          * 0 \n");
    printf("    1 1         * 1 \n");
    printf("   1 2 1        * 2 \n");
    printf("  1 3 3 1       * 3 \n");
    printf(" 1 4 6 4 1      * 4 \n");
    printf(" ****************   \n");
    printf(" 0 1 2 3 4          \n");
    printf("\n");

    // Initializing
    int row, pos;

    // Input Row
    printf("Enter the row: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    clear_input();

    // Input Position
    printf("Enter the position in the row: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);
    clear_input();

    // Initializing
    uint64_t element, element_1, element_2, element_3, element_4;

    // Previously written as -> element = ( factorial(row) ) / ( factorial(pos) * factorial(row - pos) );
    // Doesn't fix the problem
    element_1 = factorial(row);
    element_2 = factorial(pos);
    element_3 = factorial(row - pos);
    element_4 = element_2 * element_3;

    element = element_1 / element_4;

    // Print result
    printf("\n");
    printf("%"PRIu64"\n", element_1);   // Temporary output
    printf("%"PRIu64"\n", element_2);   // Temporary output
    printf("%"PRIu64"\n", element_3);   // Temporary output
    printf("%"PRIu64"\n", element_4);   // Temporary output
    printf("\n");
    printf("The element is %"PRIu64"", element);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void clear_input(void)                                          // Temporary function to clean input from the keyboard
{
  while(getchar() != '\n');
}

uint64_t factorial(int x)                                       // Function to calculate factorial
{
    int f = 1, i = x;
    if (x == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    while (i != 1) {
        f = f * i;
        i = i - 1;
    }
    return f;
}
```

Comment: If you are using large numbers (>32 bits) then using `int` is going to get you incorrect results. If you are utilizing the `uint64_t` data type to specify the return type, then you need to use the same data type to compute your calculation. Your function now uses an `int` internally and the result is implicitly cast to a `uint64_t`, which doesn't really help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factorials get [really big really fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Example) (scroll down a little to see the list). Even a 64-bit number is only good up to `20!`. So you have to do a little preprocessing before you start multiplying.

The general idea is to factor the numerator and the denominator, and remove all of the common factors. Since the results of Pascal's Triangle are always integers, you are guaranteed that the denominator will be 1 after all common factors have been removed.

For example let's say you have `row=35` and `position=10`. Then the calculation is

```
element = 35! / (10! * 25!)
```

which is

```
35 * 34 * 33 * ... * 26 * 25 * 24 * ... * 3 * 2 * 1
---------------------------------------------------
     10!                * 25 * 24 * ... * 3 * 2 * 1
```

So the first simplification is that the larger factorial in the denominator cancels all of the smaller terms of the numerator.  Which leaves

```
35 * 34 * 33 * ... * 26 
-----------------------
 10 * 9 * 8 * ... * 1
```

Now we need to remove the remaining common factors in the numerator and denominator. It helps to put all the number of the numerator in an array. Then, for each number in the denominator, compute the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm) (gcd) and divide the numerator and denominator by the gcd.

The following code demonstrates the technique.

```
array[10] = { 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26 };  

for ( d = 10; d >= 2; d-- )
{ 
    temp = d;
    for ( i = 0; i < 10 && temp > 1; i++ )
    {
        common = gcd( array[i], temp );
        array[i] /= common;
        temp /= common;
    }
}
```

Here's what the code does step by step

```
d=10   i=0   temp=10   array[0]=35  ==>  gcd(35,10)=5, so array[0]=35/5=7  and temp=10/5=2
d=10   i=1   temp=2    array[1]=34  ==>  gcd(34, 2)=2, so array[1]=34/2=17 and temp=2/2=1
inner loop breaks because temp==1
d=9    i=0   temp=9    array[0]=7   ==>  gcd(7,9)=1,  so nothing changes
d=9    i=1   temp=9    array[1]=17  ==>  gcd(17,9)=1, so nothing changes
d=9    i=2   temp=9    array[2]=33  ==>  gcd(33,9)=3, so array[2]=11 and temp=3
d=9    i=3                          ==>  gcd(32,3)=1
d=9    i=4                          ==>  gcd(31,3)=1
d=9    i=5   temp=3    array[5]=30  ==>  gcd(30,3)=3, so array[5]=10 and temp=1
inner loop breaks
```

When all is said and done the array ends up as

```
array[10] = { 1, 17, 11, 1, 31, 1, 29,  14, 3, 26 }
```

Multiply those numbers together and the answer is `183579396`, and the entire calculation could be performed using 32-bit ints. In general, as long as the answer fits into 32-bits, the calculations can be done with 32-bits.

Answer (score 3):

(my C is rusty, so this may not be super accurate)

Your factorial function is returning a uint64_t, but it's doing the computation with regular ints. If you changed f and i to uint64_t I think you'll avoid your current integer overflow issue.

However, you're still going to run into overflow pretty quickly (uint64_t will overflow around 21!). To avoid this you can be a bit smarter with the algorithm. With row=16 and position=3, you need 16! / (3! * 13!). You can cancel out most of the terms (16!/13! is just 14*15*16) and end up with 14*15*16 / (1*2*3). This'll let your program go a lot further than row 21.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calculating the factorial, even though you are returning a 64-bit integer it won't make a difference if you are using regular int variables for your intermediate calculations. Change to this:

```
uint64_t factorial(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t f = 1, i = x;
    if (x == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    while (i != 1) {
        f = f * i;
        i = i - 1;
    }
    return f;
}
```

Also, think about how you can rearrange the equation so that you don't have to calculate really large intermediate values. For example you could rearrange to this:

element = ( factorial(row) / factorial(pos) ) / factorial(row - pos);

Then you won't be multiplying two factorials together and getting a really large number.

Also, when you compute factorial(row) / factorial(pos) you can eliminate terms that will be in both factorial(row) and factorial(pos), so you don't need to calculate the entire factorials.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
    {
    printf ("\n");
    int n = 10;
    int i;
    int j;
    int x[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
         x[i] = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
         {
         for (j = n - 1; j >= 1; j--)
              x[j] = x[j-1] + x[j];

         x[0] = 1;

         int s = n - i;

         for (j = 0; j < s; j++)
              printf ("  ");

         for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
              {
              if (x[j] != 0)
                  printf (" %3d", x[j]);
              }

        printf ("\n");
        }

    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
    }
```