# Modulo of factorial divided by factorial

Tags: c++, algorithm, modulo, factorial, number-theory

How to calculate `a!/(b1! b2! ... bm!) modulo p`, where `p` is a prime number? The factorial of `a` and `b` can be very big (`long long int` is not sufficient) so I need to pass to modulo.

Comment: There are conditions for this to be an integer. Obviously, a>= max(b1,b2,...bm). Do you have more details - for example if b1+b2...bm=a then you are sure it is an integer because it is the number of ways to mix m groups of size bi without permutation inside the groups.

Comment: I know that a!/(b1! b2! ... bm!) is an integer, but since the numbers might be very big, we cannot always compute the factorials

Comment: How big is p? If not too big, a solution would be to consider number of occurrences of each prime (less than p) in the numerator and denominator. No idea if that would be optimal, but overflow could be avoided easily.

Comment: @user3386109 since p **is** prime, you can perform division by calculating modular inverses. I'll expand this into an answer.

Comment: [Removing common factors leaves a multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28058811/3386109). Then the multiplication can be performed by noting that `(a * b) mod p = ((a mod p) * (b mod p)) mod p`.

Comment: @myrtlecat I'm interested in seeing whether using modular inverses are faster than using GCDs to remove the common factors.

Comment: To remove common factors you could also get the prime factorizations of ```a!```, ```b1!```, ```b2!``` etc. and then subtract the exponents of the primes of ```a!``` by the exponents of the primes of each ```b_i!```.

Comment: @FarahMind Saying that the numbers "can be very big" is not helpful. What are the actual limits on `a`, `b` and `p`?

Comment: @user3386109 a and b can be from 40 to 60 and p is greater than 10000

Comment: That's not very big, that's small.

Comment: @KellyBundy OP only claimed that `a!` and `b!` were bigger than `long long int`, which is true

Comment: @KellyBundy 60! is bigger than unsigned long long int, is there another type that can supporte thsi order of number?

Comment: Then you can precompute at compile time the prime factors for all possible values of a and b and do it like Oli L suggested. As you confirmed, the fraction is an integer. Then you can combine as many factors as still fit into `long long int` and do `modulo` with `p` before multiplying the next prime factors of the integer.

Comment: I would go with the previous suggestion with storing prime factors. You have about 19 prime factors below 60. You would have a 2D array storing those for 1..60 and you can initialize it with the correct values (by calculating externally and pasting into the code or by using `constexpr` functions, which do the calculations normally, but are executed at compile time). A second 1D array stores the prime numbers. As soon as you know the prime factors of the fraction result, it is a simple loop multiplying and from time to time do modulo (%).

Comment: I would start with this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019252/create-n-element-constexpr-array-in-c11/34465458#34465458 then change the array to two dimensions and instead of `arr[i] = i` insert a prime factor calculation `arr[i][p] = c`, where `c` is how often `i` can be divided by `p`. That is calculated at compile time and can be reasonably inefficient.

Comment: @myrtlecat Nah, that's not really how they phrased it. They could've, but additionally said very big. Java for example has a class that easily supports integers with millions of digits, and even that isn't called `VeryBigInteger` :-). To me, the word "very" implies something much bigger than 82 digits (at least millions) and performance being an issue.

Answer (score 5):

If `a`, `b`s and `p` are fairly small, prefer @KellyBundy's approach of cancelling factors, or counting prime factors.

#### Multiplication and modular arithmetic

Given integers `m` and `n` and some other integer `k`:

```
(m * n) modulo k = ((m modulo k) * (n mod k)) modulo k
```

This allows a large product to be calculated `modulo p` without worrying about overflow, since we can always keep the arguments in the range `[0, k)`.

For example to compute the factorial `a! modulo k`, in python:

```py
def fact(a, k):
    if a == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return ((a % k) * fact(a - 1, k)) % k
```

#### Division and modular arithmetic

If `p` is a **prime** then for any integer `n` that is not divisible by `p`, we can find an integer which I'll call `inv(n)` such that:

```
(n * inv(n)) modulo p = 1
```

This number is called the [modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `n`. There are various algorithms to find modular inverses, which I won't describe here (but see e.g. [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_inverse)).

Now, given integers `n` and `m`, and **assuming that `m / n` is an integer**, we can apply the rule:

```
(m / n) modulo p = (m * inv(n)) modulo p
```

So provided we can calculate modular inverses, we can convert division to multiplication, and then apply the previous rule.

Comment: This answer makes it sound like canceling factors is optional, but in general you must first cancel at least factors of p. The reason is hinted at in other parts of the answer. Suppose (m/n) is an integer; then so is (p*m)/(p*n). But if you don't cancel p then the denominator is not invertible and the numerator is zero.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.

Comment: Since OP says that modulus is a prime, `inv(x)` can be `pow(x, p-2, p)` by Fermat's little theorem (using Python's `pow` function).

Comment: the third parameter being the modulus

Answer (score 4):

Another way, listing the factors `1` to `a`, then canceling with all divisors, then multiplying modulo p:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int gcd(int a, int b) {
  return b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
}

int main() {
  int a = 60;
  std::vector<int> bs = {13, 7, 19};
  int p = 10007;

  std::vector<int> factors(a);
  for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
    factors[i] = i + 1;
  for (int b : bs) {
    while (b > 1) {
      int d = b--;
      for (int& f : factors) {
        int g = gcd(f, d);
        f /= g;
        d /= g;
      }
    }
  }
  int result = 1;
  for (int f : factors)
    result = result * f % p;
  std::cout << result;
}
```

Prints 5744, same as this Python code:

```py
from math import factorial, prod

a = 60
bs = [13, 7, 19]
p = 10007

num = factorial(a)
den = prod(map(factorial, bs))
print(num // den % p)
```