# Program does not show correct answers for higher values

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //Write C code here
    int n, r, a, b, c, i, fact;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &r);
    fact = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact = fact * i;
        if (i == r) {
            a = fact;
        }
        if (i == n - r) {
            b = fact;
        }
    }
    c = fact / (a * b);
    printf("the ncr is %d", c);

    return 0;
}
```

For values like 18C2 etc correct answer is not shown when compiled in an online compiler

The program shows correct answers for small values like 12C5 or 5C3
But for larger values the answer comes as wrong. For 18C2 the answer shown is 3.
When I used the same compiler to do `(24 * 23) / 2` it shows sedimentation error.

Comment: Sounds like integer overflow. What is `13!` ? Can an `int` hold that number?

Comment: Instead of `int` you can use `uint64_t` if supported on your system. Then you can handle a bit higher input values but not much higher. If your system have a 128 bit integer try it. But in general you'll need special code to calculate stuff like `100!`. The result can't be held by a simple integer

Comment: [You need to use a different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058019/pascals-triangle-in-c/) when computing `nCr` for large values of `n`. Even with `uint64_t` and the right approach, you can only go to `n=67` before overflow becomes a problem. For example, 67C34 is 1.4e19, but 68C34 is 2.8e19 which overflows a 64-bit integer.

Comment: Check this code https://ideone.com/UJXY6k and you see that the calculation of `fact` overflows pretty fast.

Comment: The use of the "compiler-errors" tag is almost always incorrect, as it is here. The error is almost always between the keyboard and the seat.

Comment: Also if you are getting a sedimentation error, then your compiler was written by a geologist.

Comment: @MarkAdler: it is a cute typo, but it can certainly cause a lot of aggradation.

Answer (score 3):

That is a terrible way to compute a binomial. 18!, as well as 13!, are larger than 2<sup>31</sup>-1, and so overflow the usual `int`. In fact, you only need to go to 21! to overflow a `uint64_t`. (No, this is not a "compiler error" as suggested in a tag. You are not understanding the limitations of the data types.)

You can compute much, much larger binomials even with just the `int` type by never multiplying out *n!*. There is a lot of cancellation going on. This shows why it is a good idea to do a calculation by hand first, so that you can see what's going on, instead of just jumping in and writing code.

For example 18C2 should not be a problem *at all*. It is 18!/(16!2!), where 18!/16! is just 18 * 17. You should pick *k* to be small, e.g. if you had 18C16, you would change that to the equivalent 18C2. Then *n!/(n-k)!* will throw out at least half of the terms of *n!*. Then with what's left, and the use of some binomial identities, you can cancel terms in the numerator and denominator (*k!*) as you go along, avoiding overflows and fractional results.

Even better, at least for smaller *n*, you could do it with just additions by filling in Pascal's triangle. Along with saving the results in memory, this is super fast.

Here is code that combines Pascal's triangle with direct calculations. This uses fast table lookups up to `MAXN`, and calculations after that, with the ability to return any binomial that is less than 2<sup>64</sup> (except for (2<sup>64</sup>-1)C1, which will appear to be an overflow due to the special return value):

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Binary GCD algorithm. This assumes that a and b are positive.
uint64_t gcd(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
    int z = __builtin_ctzll(a | b);
    a >>= __builtin_ctzll(a);
    do {
        b >>= __builtin_ctzll(b);
        b -= a;
        uint64_t m = (int64_t)b >> 63;
        a += b & m;
        b = (b + m) ^ m;
    } while (b);
    return a << z;
}

// Return n C k or (uint64_t)-1 on overflow. This assumes that 1 < k <= n/2.
static uint64_t binom_calc(uint64_t n, uint64_t k) {
    uint64_t c = n & 1 ? n * ((n - 1) >> 1) : (n >> 1) * (n - 1);
    for (uint64_t i = 3; i <= k; i++) {
        uint64_t m = n - i + 1;
        uint64_t g = gcd(m, i);
        m /= g;
        c /= i / g;
        if ((uint64_t)-1 / c < m)
            return -1;
        c *= m;
    }
    return c;
}

// MAXN is the maximum n for which the table is used. Special MAXN values:
//     967 -- binom_calc() only used for k <= 7
//    1913 -- binom_calc() only used for k <= 6
//    4868 -- binom_calc() only used for k <= 5
//   18580 -- binom_calc() only used for k <= 4
#define MAXN 1913
static uint64_t binom_table[MAXN-3][32] = {0};

// Return n C k or (uint64_t)-1 on overflow. This assumes that 0 < 2*k <= n+1.
static uint64_t binom_recur(uint64_t n, uint64_t k) {
    if (n < (k << 1))
        k--;
    if (k == 1)
        return n;
    if (binom_table[n - 4][k - 2])
        return binom_table[n - 4][k - 2];
    uint64_t a = binom_recur(n - 1, k - 1);
    uint64_t b = binom_recur(n - 1, k);
    a += b;
    return binom_table[n - 4][k - 2] = a < b ? (uint64_t)-1 : a;
}

// Return n C k, or 0 if k > n, or (uint64_t)-1 on overflow. This is not
// thread-safe unless and until binom_fill() is called. Otherwise, the table is
// filled in on an as-needed basis.
uint64_t binom(uint64_t n, uint64_t k) {
    if (k > n)
        return 0;
    if (k > (n >> 1))
        k = n - k;
    if (k == 0)
        return 1;
    if (k == 1)
        return n;
    return n > MAXN ? binom_calc(n, k) : binom_recur(n, k);
}

// Fill in the binomial table. If you do this once from the main thread, then
// binom() can safely be used from multiple threads at the same time. This only
// takes about 140 microseconds on an Apple M1 for MAXN = 1913.
void binom_fill(void) {
    for (uint64_t n = MAXN, k = 2; n >= 4; n--)
        for (; k <= (n << 1); k++)
            if (binom_recur(n, k) + 1 == 0)
                break;
}
```

To go further, you can bust through the 64-bit barrier and use the [bignum library](https://gmplib.org).

Comment: You don't really need a look-up table, and using double recursion can be very slow. You can just calculate nCi = (nC{i-1} * (n-i+1))/i for i = 2 to r where nC1 = n.

Comment: There's no recursion once the table is filled in, which takes less than a microsecond. Also, the double recursion is not slow at all, since it stops once it gets to an already filled-in value. And it's only additions, no large multiplications or divisions. A direct calculation could be faster if you're only computing one binomial. Though that would be an odd application.

Comment: Also that formula will only make it up to 62C31 before overflowing the multiply. The Pascal triangle additions make it all the way to 67C33 with 64-bit arithmetic, which is as far as you can go for a filled-in row.

Comment: @SimonGoater That method still suffers from overflow. For example to compute 14C6 you would need to evaluate the expression `2002*9/6`. Since 6 doesn't divide evenly into 2002 or 9, you need to do the multiplication first (risking overflow), or you need to eliminate common factors. Using unsigned 64-bit numbers, the first overflow (without common factor elimination) occurs when computing 63C30.

Comment: Though I can fix Simon's formula with GCD. At each step, `m = n - i + 1; g = gcd(m, i); c = (c / (i / g)) * (m / g);`. Then it makes it all the way. Wikipedia provides a fast binary GCD implementation in Rust, easily translatable to C.