# iOS 10 bug on device but not on simulator

Tags: iphone, swift, ios10

My code calls `String.appendingFormat` to append a formatted string to a value that is used as output in an iPhone app.  When the call includes the format string and two value arguments (e.g. `("The numbers are %d and %d", number1, number2))`, it works fine on the simulator, but on my iPad, the second value is always treated as zero.

Note that, in each case, the value comes from a `Int64` array.

Why would it work differently on an actual device than in the simulator?

Here's a better-formatted version of my reply (one of these days, I'm going to remember that newlines get swallowed in replies):

```
var results = [Int64]()
var A: Int64 = 123
results.append(A)
```

On the simulator, results[0] = 123

On the iPad, results[0] = what looks like a pointer; it's an 11-digit number that changes each time the code is executed

```
var outputString: String = ""
outputString = outputString.appendingFormat("%d %d", A, results[0])
```

On the simulator, outputString = "123 123"

On the iPad, outputString = "123 0"

Comment: Need your code to debug.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8679/642626

Comment: print like this. `print("The numbers are \(number1) and \(number2)")`

Comment: Here's the quick version:

`var results = [Int64]();
var A: Int64 = 123;
results.append(A)`

On the simulator, results[0] = 123
On the iPad, results[0] = what looks like a pointer; it's an 11-digit number that changes each time the code is executed

`var outputString: String = "";
 outputString = outputString.appendingFormat("%d %d", A, results[0])`

On the simulator, outputString = "10 123"
On the iPad, outputString = "10 0"

Comment: sorry don't get it .. where is the 10 from now and where is the 11 digit number and .. :D sorry

Comment: Good catch - both of the 10s should be 123 (originally, I had A = 10, but changed it to 123 to make it a little easier to read)

Comment: How are you getting the output string?  Can you show us your print line?

Comment: I'm getting correct results on iOS10 on a 6Plus.  "print(outputString)
        print("The numbers are \(A) and \(results[0])")" is giving me "123 123
The numbers are 123 and 123"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Bryan Chen's link was the solution - what was happening was, since I was using %d instead of %lld, every Int64 was being displayed as its four low bytes in decimal, followed by its four high bytes.  When I added additional arguments to the call, it would show the first argument, then zero, then the second argument, then zero, and so on.