# Finding biggest prime number in user-inputted number - C

Tags: c

I have a problem with my code. The topic is to write a C program which finds biggest prime number in the number inputted by user.

Ex.:
Enter number: 46656665326

Output: 66566653

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_prime(unsigned long long a)
{
    if(a<=1)
        return 0;
    if(a==2)
        return 1;
    for(unsigned long long p=2; p<a; p++)
        if(a%p==0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

unsigned long long find_largest_prime_number(unsigned long long number)
{
    unsigned long long prime=0;
    int count=0;
    unsigned long long count2=1;
    unsigned long long pom=0;
    unsigned long long pom3=0;
    pom3=number;
    while(pom3!=0)
    {
        count++;
        pom3/=10;
    }
    count++;
    int pom_1=0;
    while(pom_1<count)
    {
        count2*=10;
        pom_1++;
    }
    pom=number;
    while(count2>=10)
    {
        unsigned long long pom2=pom;
        while(pom2!=0)
        {
            if(is_prime(pom2))
                if(pom2>prime)
                    prime=pom2;
            pom2/=10;
        }
        count2/=10;
        pom=pom%count2;
    }
    return prime;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long x=0;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    int n1=scanf("%llu", &x);
    if(n1!=1)
    {
        printf("incorrect input");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%llu", find_largest_prime_number(x));
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is it works with max 13-digit number but it freezes when the input number has more than 13 digits.
Ex. it freezes when I enter: 215911504934497

Please help, what's wrong with the code?

Comment: @Blaze isn't %llu the correct one for unsigned long long? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-format-an-unsigned-long-long-int-using-printf

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where exactly does the execution get stuck?

Comment: Could it be a problem with `count` or `pom`, as they are integers and might not be long enough to support `x` more than 13-digits?

Comment: @NicoHaase It works with max 13-digit number but it freezes when the input number has more than 13 digits. Ex. it freezes when I enter: 215911504934497, ex.: https://imgur.com/271Ypy2 (12-digit one, works), https://imgur.com/EfoL2LQ (15-digit one, freezes)

Comment: @Samleo No, firstly I used unsigned long long for them too, didn't helped. Also, int is enough for them because they only count the steps

Comment: What have you tried to **debug** the problem? Have you checked which parts of your code cause the freezing?

Comment: Is it freezing because the program takes too long? Or are there any errors? (The code is very inefficient btw)

Comment: BTW: your question boils down to this: why does `is_prime(215911504934497LL)` block. All other code is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @NicoHaase I have written some printfs between some code lines, ex. after this: while(pom_1<count)
    {
        count2*=10;
        pom_1++;
    } to see if the count2 is correct and it is, also count counts correctly but I guess sth might be wrong while working with this 'main' part: while(count2>=10) and everything after that

Comment: @Samleo Yeah, I know it is inefficient but I've just started learning programming

Comment: @Jabberwocky Do you mean that the problem is in is_prime?

Comment: That's fine. My point is that because your code doesn't seem to throw errors (or am I wrong), the issue is not that the program has errors, but that it's too slow

Comment: @geekon Yes. The code is perfectly correct. It is simply terribly inefficient and therefore takes a very, very long time just to find out if a single large number is prime.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Any suggestions how to make it more efficient?

Comment: @geekon you could start stopping at the square root of the number to be tested and only test if it's divisible by odd numbers. If it's not divisible by 2 it's pointless to test if it's divisible by 4, 6, 7. etc. There are other methods though.

Comment: Hint: google nively: "c find out if number is prime"

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ok, thanks for suggestions, will try to improve that.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Finally solved the issue by using square root, thanks for help!

Comment: @geekon this SO article might be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453793/which-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-find-prime-numbers

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("incorrect input");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  suggest using: `fprintf( stderr, "incorrect input" );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly correct. It is simply terribly inefficient and therefore takes very, very long time just to find out if a single large number is prime.

Here is better version of `is_prime`:

- It tests divisors only up to the square root of the number to be tested.
- It only tests odd divisors, if the number is not divisible by two, it's pointless to test if it's divisible by 4, 6, 8 etc.

---

```
// long long integer square root found somewhere on the internet
unsigned long long isqrt(unsigned long long x)
{
  unsigned long long op, res, one;

  op = x;
  res = 0;

  /* "one" starts at the highest power of four <= than the argument. */
  one = 1LL << 62;  /* second-to-top bit set */
  while (one > op) one >>= 2;

  while (one != 0) {
    if (op >= res + one) {
      op -= res + one;
      res += one << 1;  // <-- faster than 2 * one  
    }
    res >>= 1;
    one >>= 2;
  }
  return res;
}


int is_prime(unsigned long long a)
{
  if (a <= 1 || a == 2 || a % 2 == 0)
    return 0;

  unsigned long long count = 0;
  unsigned long long limit = isqrt(a) + 1;

  for (unsigned long long p = 3; p < limit; p += 2)
  {
    if (a % p == 0)
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Further optimisations are of course possible. E.g. it is also pointless to test for multiples of 3 if the number was not divisible by 3 etc. Also if you want to find a range of prime numbers there are probably other approaches to be taken into account.

Comment: For the optimisations you are talking about, you would have to use the sieve of Erathoneses as detailed in my answer

Comment: @Samleo not sure, Sieve of Erastothenes is great for small values but for huge values you just need too much memory. But there are definitely more advanced algorithms, the one we're using here is pretty naive and inefficient (even with my improvements).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for block boils down to this:

```
int is_prime(unsigned long long a)
{
    ...
    for(unsigned long long p=2; p<a; p++)
        if(a%p==0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

If you enter `215911504934497` then the `find_largest_prime_number` will call `is_prime(215911504934497)`. `215911504934497` is a big number, and doing `a%p` for each p from 2 to `215911504934497` is cpu expensive (I think at least you could `p < a/2`). Your program get's stuck in this loop. You can observe that by doing a simple printf inside it:

```
int is_prime(unsigned long long a)
{
    ...
    for(unsigned long long p=2; p<a; p++) {
        printf("%lld %lld\n", p, a);
        if(a%p==0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on square root finally solved the issue.
is_prime should be looking like that:

```
int is_prime(unsigned long long a)
{
    int i=0;
    int count=0;
    int test=0;
    int limit=sqrt(a)+1;
    if(a<=1)
        return 0;
    if(a==2)
        return 1;
    if(a%2==0)
        test=1;
    else
        for(i=3; i<limit && !test; i+=2, count++)
            if(a%i==0)
                test=1;
    if(!test)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `sqrt` is OK for huge 64 bit integers.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Hmm but it works fine for me for numbers with more than 13 digits

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure if it would work correctly for 17-18 digit numbers. I didn't investigate though.

Comment: OK, good for you. BTW your image is not a proof, you should have a look at https://www.ideone.com/, this is great for posting small programs like [this one for example](https://www.ideone.com/lqCs3x)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you, didn't know about the site

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other contributors, and in the comments, your code is "crashing" simply because it is inefficient.

Many of the other contributors have used a more efficient way of checking whether a number is prime by checking that number against its divisors.

HOWEVER, this is **not** the most efficient manner to go about doing it, especially if you are whether multiple numbers are prime.

In order to make it even faster, I suggest an implementation of [the Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

```
#define MAX_N 4294967296 //idk how big of an array your computer can actually handle. I'm using 2^32 here.

//Declare as a global variable for extra memory allocation
//unsigned char is used as it is only 1 byte (smallest possible memory alloc)
//0 for FALSE, 1 for TRUE.
unsigned char is_prime[MAX_N+1];

//Populate the is_prime function up to your input number (or MAX_N, whichever is smaller)
//This is done in O(N) time, where N is your number.
void performSieve(unsigned long long number){
    unsigned long long i,j;
    unsigned long long n = (number>MAX_N)?MAX_N:number; //quick way (ternary operator): "whichever is smaller"

    //Populating array with default as prime
    for(i=2; i<=n; i++) is_prime[i] = 1;

    for(i=4; i<=n; i+=2) is_prime[i] = 0; //all even numbers except 4 is not prime
    for(i=3; i<=n; i+=2){
        if(is_prime[i] == 1)
            for(j=i*i;j<=n;j+=i){ //all the multiples of i except i itself are NOT prime
                is_prime[i] == 0;
            }
    }    
}

//isPrime function
unsigned char isPrime(unsigned long long n){
    if(n<=1) return 0; //edge cases

    //Check if we can find the prime number in our gigantic sieve
    if(n<=MAX_N){
        return is_prime[n]; //this is O(1) time (constant time, VERY FAST!)
    }

    //Otherwise, we now use the standard "check all the divisors" method
    //with all the optimisations as suggested by previous users:
    if(n%2==0) return 0; //even number

    //This is from user @Jabberwocky
    unsigned long long limit = isqrt(a);

    for (unsigned long long p = 3; p <= limit; p += 2) {
        if (a % p == 0) return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You'll have trouble with that method for really big numbers. And here you are allocating 4GB of memory, not sure this will work on most platforms and `4294967296` is not really a big number when it's about big prime numbers.

Comment: Yes I know you'll have trouble, which is why i added a secondary optimisation where if the number is too large, Sieve of Erath will not work.

Comment: There might be a way around the memory problem using individual bits in a character that is more complicated. So you take an integer and think of it not as a decimal integer but as a binary number with individual bits referring to the true and false of whether that number is prime