# Printing an unsigned long in hex in c

Tags: c

I have troubles with printing a big 16 digits hex number in c

```
unsigned long long j = 0x89ABCDEF12893456;
printf("0x%lx\n", j); //prints: 0x12893456
printf("%#lx", j); //prints: 0x12893456
```

is there a way to print the whole number?

Comment: Try `%#018llx` (`ll` == `long long`)

Comment: The `l` length modifier is for `long` and `unsigned long`.  The `ll` length modifier is for `long long` and `unsigned long long`.  You have mismatched arguments, resulting in undefined behavior.  For `unsigned long long`, use `%llx`, `%llu`, etc.

Comment: If your compiler didn't tell you about that mistake, turn on warnings so it does (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you format an unsigned long long int using printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-format-an-unsigned-long-long-int-using-printf)

Answer (score 2):

As per the C standard, `C11 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions /7` which discusses length modifiers:

> `ll` (ell-ell): Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `long long int` or `unsigned long long int` argument; or that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `long long int` argument.

A *single* `l` specifies a `long` or `unsigned long`. Hence `%llx` or `%#llx` is the format specifier you want, possibly with an output length and zero padding as well, if you want the numbers to line up (such as `"0x%016llx"`).

Answer (score 1):

That should do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

unsigned long long j = 0x89ABCDEF12893456;    
printf("%#llx", j); 
return 0;
}
```