# Why is there such an output?

Tags: c

This is the C program：

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long int number = 4294967295;
    printf("unsigned long long int size is: %d byte \n", sizeof(unsigned long long int));
    printf("this value is: %d\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

this is the output：

```
unsigned long long int size is: 8 byte
this value is: -1
```

why output is -1 instead of 4294967295

Comment: Look up the documentation for printf format strings and check specifically what `%d` means

Comment: Q: why output is -1 instead of 4294967295?  A: because you printed it with `%d`!  Unfortunately, different compilers have different "printf" format strings for "unsigned long long": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844

Answer (score 4):

In the printf statement, you have written **"%d"** which is for **int** instead of **"%llu"** which is for **unsigned long long int**

So for getting the correct output your statement should be

```
printf("this value is: %llu\n", number);
```

For more please look at this link below:

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-types-in-c/