# Sum of big numbers sequence

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long int sum = 0LL;
    long i;
    for (i = 0LL; i < 100000000; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    printf("%i", sum);
}
```

that's all of my code, and I am curious why it prints 887459712 instead of 4999999950000000, and how to fix this

Comment: Try "%ld" instead of "%i".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `sum` is declared `unsigned long int`, which is big enough for your expected result.
The problem is not overflow.

The problem is your `printf` statement is wrong.

You told it to print a "normal" sized int with `%i`, which only goes up to about 4.2 billion.

You should tell `printf` to print an `unsigned long int`, using `%llu`
It should be:

```
printf("%llu", sum);
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/pXfrLd)

### Results

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5376KB
4999999950000000
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-format-an-unsigned-long-long-int-using-printf

Comment: 4999999950000000 is a little more than 2^52, so `long int` (signed or not) is only a large enough container if you're working on a 64-bit system; on a 32-bit (or smaller) system, it's not enough. Since the OP didn't specify the platform, you might want to do that in your answer, or else suggest `long long int`, which is 64 bits either way.

Comment: @Caleb Yes, and `long long` is implied by OP's use of `0LL`